# Excel if selection is cut then do things

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook and need to run a macro on rows that are cut and inserted

I already have code that runs when one cell in a row changes that changes the color of a cell in another sheet with the same value.

That code is in the worksheet_Change sub.

My question is How do i detect if target has been cut and inserted rather than just typed in?

EDIT**

Thanks to Mark Fitzgerald i realized i need to give more information.

I have 2 sheets one has rows of data with a blank row then a header for each group of data

the other sheet is set up in columns so each column has the header info then the first cell from each of the rows that are in the group.

when someone cuts and inserts some rows from one group on the row sheet the related cells in the column sheet to move to the relevant column.

The rows will NEVER be copy and pasted nor will the values move independently of the row.

Code Below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim batchNo
' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("m1:m5000")
Set batchNo = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row)

If Target.count = 1 Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "x"

        Case "y"

        Case Else
            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End Select

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Dim c
        With Sheets("columnsheet").Range("d12:fz144")
            Set c = .Find(batchNo, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Workbooks("Work In Process.xls").Activate
                Worksheets("columnsheet").Activate
                ActiveSheet.Range(c.Address).Activate
                Select Case Target.Value
                Case "x"

                Case "y"

                Case Else
                    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End Select
                Workbooks("Work In Process.xls").Activate
                Worksheets("rowsheet").Activate
            End If
        End With
    End If
ElseIf (Target.count > 1) Then
                                      'if entire row or rows are selected
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I removed most of the cases because they made it more cluttered but all they do is change text colour and background colour

Comment: Could you show your existing `Worksheet_Change` code?  Also, I think I understand how your sheets are laid out but would like to see before and after images of both sheets just to be sure.  I think what you are asking can probably be done.

Comment: I think I almost have it.  Are you monitoring rowsheet in Work in Process.xls or is that a separate workbook?

Comment: Its the same workbook

Comment: What happens to the cell relationship to batchNo for cells below the inserted cell?  It seems to me there will be a disconnect.

Comment: What do you mean by a "disconnect"? I had hoped I could assign batchNo to cell A# while looping through the selection

Comment: Say you insert a cell in M10 which, prior to the insertion had a batchNo = 8, the newly inserted M10 will have batchNo = 8 and the old M10 will get M11s batchNo.  Hence the disconnect.  Where would a new batchNo come from?

Comment: Its inserting an entire row. when the user inserts they cut multiple rows from a group with an "unassigned" header and when they insert, all rows below will get shifted down

Comment: I still think it can probably be done but will need to think on it for a while.  In the absence of images, am I right in thinking that `columnsheet` range("D12:FZ144") has "Group" headers in row 12 with applicable batchNos for each "Group" listed directly below them and that you want to cut the batchNos from the source "Group" and paste them below the destination "Group" header?

Comment: in columnsheet rows 3-7 have group header information and 8-11 have calculations to do with the group, so batchNos start in row 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i solved this was by checking if the selection was an entire row

```
If Target.count > 0 Then
    Dim r As Range
    If Target.Columns.count = ActiveSheet.Columns.count Then        ' if entire row
        If Target.rows.count > 1 Then                               ' multiple rows
            For Each r In Target.rows                               
                DoStuff r
            Next r
        Else                                                        'single row
            DoStuff Target
        End If
    ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.rows.count > 1 Then                               ' multiple items
            For Each r In Target.rows                               ' do stuff for each item
                DoOtherStuff r
            Next r
        Else                                                        'single item
            DoOtherStuff Target
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 potential ways, excluding macros, to change a cell value without actually typing anything in the cell:

1. Drag and drop from another cell on the sheet
2. Copy and paste from another cell, sheet or even workbook
3. Cut and paste from another cell, sheet or workbook

If you want to stop users from dragging and dropping into a cell or range of cells, you can disable that functionality whenever the sheet is activated.  Be sure to re-enable it when you deactivate the sheet because it's an Application setting which applies to all sheets in all open workbooks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
End Sub
```

You will notice that the mouse pointer doesn't change to 4 arrows when you hover over a non-blank cells borders.  I found an undocumented side-effect that disabling CellDragAndDrop also clears the clipboard if you are trying to copy something from another sheet or workbook.

To prevent cutting and pasting from within the sheet, you need to catch it before it happens by checking if CutCopyMode (i.e. there are marching ants around a selection) is true when the cell selection changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.CutCopyMode <> False Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        MsgBox "Cut or Copy & Paste is not allowed on this sheet", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear but I don't want to stop users from cutting and pasting, i want some code to run when cutting and inserting rows that moves cells on another sheet(I already have code for this i just need to know when to run it)